# :hover seems to not work and i have no idea why

Tags: html, css

I don't know why, but `hover` won't change the opacity of the image. I've even tried to make a separate HTML page and it has the same problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    #div24 img:hover {
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div24">
    <h3>OPACITY 0.2</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="1" style="opacity: 0.2;">
    <h3>OPACITY 0.5</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="2" style="opacity: 0.5;">
    <h3>OPACITY 1</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="1" style="opacity: 1.0;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Inline `style=“”` attributes always override rules in `<style>` elements.

Comment: Thank you a lot that fixes a lot of my problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) in the specification.

A rule in a style attribute will always override a rule with a selector (unless you use `!important` which is almost always more trouble then it is worth).

Replace your style attributes with, for example, classes and put the rules in your stylesheet with suitable (i.e. lower or equal to `#div24 img:hover`) specificity.

Answer (score 1):

you are giving inline css, and the priority is more of that compared to on page style block

you should do it in this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style media="screen">
#div24 img {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
#div24 img:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div24">
  <h3>OPACITY 0.2</h3>
  <img src="img01.jpg" alt="1">
  <h3>OPACITY 0.5</h3>
  <img src="img01.jpg" alt="2">
  <h3>OPACITY 1</h3>
  <img src="img01.jpg" alt="1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

As is mentioned your inline style is overriding any attempt to affect opacity:

Here is a better way to do it:

```
<h3>OPACITY 0.2</h3>
<img class="changeme" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ep3jK1bZrB8/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="1">

.changeme {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.changeme:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7mo8ygxn/

Answer (score -1):

instead of putting inline css first style each image through internal css then try it. it should work